# How to make an object jump automatically in unity 5.6?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game which has the thematic Cubes. I make that game in Unity3D and c#. I want to make a cube(obstacle) jump automatically infinite times, without ever stopping.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a physics material to your object with 0 friction and 1 bounciness.

For more about physics materials, check this document: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

There is also a tutorial for the subject: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-materials

Comment: And the dynamic and static friction should be to 0?

Comment: Thanks I now fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

You should look up transform.position in the unity docs. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

Also read up on creating a coroutine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But still I have a problem: when I start the level, the cube wich needs to jump goes in the air but never come back. How I make that to come back?

Comment: Thanks I  now fixed my issue